# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Tuple

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement c# linq expression that will allow me to extract data based on years and months.The error is thrown in the where method of my context.

I am currently getting the error

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'
```

Linq expression

```
var periodTuples = period.ToList() // gives you List<KeyValuePair<int, int[]>>
                .SelectMany(kvp =>
                    kvp.Value.Select(it2 => Tuple.Create(kvp.Key, it2))).ToHashSet(); // to optimize .Contains()


benchmark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>()
                .Where(x => x.Mtd != null && x.IndexId == benchMark1 && periodTuples.Contains(Tuple.Create(x.PriceDate.Year, x.PriceDate.Month))).Select(x => x.Mtd);
```

The Where method define in my context

```
public IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            try
            {
                using (new TimedLogger(_perfLogger, GetCompletedText("Where")))
                {
                    return Authorize(_repo.Where(predicate).ToList(), AuthAccessLevel.Read);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Tuple.Create` can't be translated into SQL.

Comment: Then what is the way around

Answer (score 1):

Try a join?

```
            var benchmark1Returns = GetViewService<MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE>()
                .Where(x => x.Mtd != null && x.IndexId == benchMark1)
                .Join(periodTuples,
                    b1r => new { x = b1r.PriceDate.Year, y = b1r.PriceDate.Month },
                    tuple => new { x = tuple.Item1, y = tuple.Item2 },
                    (b, t) => b.Mtd);
```

Answer (score 1):

EF6 does not support (cannot translate to SQL) `Tuple.Create` (and `Tuple<>` constructors), in-memory collection joins, `Contains` of in-memory collection on non primitive types and many others.

The solution in your case is to replace (int year, int month) pair with primitive type expression like this:

```
int period = 12 * year + (month - 1)
```

and use it for filtering, e.g.

```
var periods = period.ToList() // gives you List<KeyValuePair<int, int[]>>
    .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value, (year, month) => 12 * year + (month - 1));
```

and then inside the LINQ query

```
periods.Contains(12 * x.PriceDate.Year + (x.PriceDate.Month - 1))
```

Note that in LINQ to Entities query `periods` doesn't need to be `HashSet<int>` (or `List<int>` etc.) - `IEnumerable<int>` is enough because it will be evaluated locally once and converted to SQL `IN (val1, val2, ..., valN)` criteria.